# Can't connect to apple update server on macOS

Tags: macos, software-update

I'm trying to download the macOS 12 InstallAssistant.pkg from apple server on MacOS from the direct download link : http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/38/12/071-51840-A_R2JDKNM0LX/wqollynqs6j5006166tvw4rliu9htf7swu/InstallAssistant.pkg. However, I'm getting the error can't connect to server on both Safari and Chrome.

I tried from my phone and the link seems to work and download begins. What could be a possible reason for this?

Comment: Works on my Mac in Safari so it must be something on your computer - sorry can't be of more help

Comment: Are the phone and the Mac on the same network? Many corporate networks block things.  For example, Mac is on corporate network but phone is on cellular or a public wifi.  If they are on the same network check the DNS settings on the Mac.  Try manually setting either google DNS 8.8.8.8 or Cloudflare 1.1.1.1.

Comment: Downloaded it fine with wget on two different machines just to see if I could.  It's not something I'd ever use, but adding it to my Installers archive anyway.  Sounds like @EzekielElin is right.

Comment: Solved it by editing the contents of ect/host file. Some malware had altered it.